# Query regarding Backlog Levels in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

[image]I'm trying to configure and customize the Azure DevOps tool as per the requirement for my application development team. In the boards setting, I have selected the option "Bugs are managed with Tasks" to get a good view of my sprint items. However, my team reports post production issues as Bugs in the tool and enabling the above mentioned setting doesn't allow me to view these Bugs in the Kanban Boad. Reason is they are not linked with any User Story.

I have been exploring the options in Backlog levels options available in the Processes settings and found that the Backlog level "Stories" is tagged only for User Story.

My query here is can i try linking Bug and Task to the already existing "Stories" backlog level. Azure DevOps does gives option to create a custom backlog level and custom Work item type. I would like to customize the existing functionality to best fit my team. Please let me know if there is a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Query regarding Backlog Levels in Azure Devops

This behavior is **by designed** and there is no way to fix it at present for the exists Work item type **Bug**.

Because there is only **one requirement backlog and it cannot be removed, but can be renamed and edited**:

[image]

There is an [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/822537/issue-work-item-type-does-not-appear-in-backlog.html) about this request on the Developer Community.

As workaround, we could create a custom the Work item type and add it to backlog level, for example, I create a custom Work item type `BugWithoutTask`, then add it portfolio backlog:

[image]

**Then** go to backlog settings and **enable new backlog**:

[image]

Now, we could these `BugwithoutTask` in the Kanban Boad:

[image]

You could check [this document](http://www.almguide.com/2017/03/adding-backlog-levels-to-vsts/) for some more deails.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leo for the response. I have explored the method to add a custom Work Item and creating a new backlog level. It seems at present this is the only possible work around.